# What am I doing wrong with this ifelse, is.na, lag function in RStudio? Failing to return the following correct 0 and 1

Tags: r, dplyr

Need help to correct my code since it's returning incorrect values. Below is my dataframe:

```
df1 <- structure(list(time = structure(c(1613331000, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
1613331300, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1613331600, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1613331900
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), value1 = c(5.68, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 3.57, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.75, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0
), value2 = c(0.0195194035275764, 0.0387245255910196, 0.00162031204013874, 
0.0086653793112231, 0.0244045196814313, 5.0142002638127, 0.00389385395628555, 
0.0047142460835886, 0.00239093814854349, 0.00187517052122717, 
0.000630486008603659, 0.00144237859581879, 0.00126141089854626, 
0.0000177735700308129, 0.000335643594999671, 0.012771405154744
), test = c(NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))
```

The logic I am trying to recreate is to output a "1" to df2$test if the current and previous four value2 inputs are less than value1. Output "0" if atleast one current or previous four value2's is equal or greater than value1. I would like to add up the instances of 1's for my result. If possible, leave NA on rows that do not have a time.

Heres is my code, any suggestions greatly appreciated, first time poster.

```
df2 <-  df1 %>%
mutate (test = 0,
test = ifelse(is.na(value1) < value2, 0, 1),
test = ifelse(is.na(value1) < lag(value2, k=1),0, 1),
test = ifelse(is.na(value1) < lag(value2, k=2),0, 1),
test = ifelse(is.na(value1) < lag(value2, k=3),0, 1),
test = ifelse(is.na(value1) < lag(value2, k=4),0, 1))
View(df2)
```

Comment: Rather than an image of your data, please include some actual data that we can test your code with. For example, use `dput(head(df1, n = 10))` and paste the output into your question.

Comment: Took a few minutes to recreate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `zoo`'s `rollapplyr`  :

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  mutate(last4max = zoo::rollapplyr(value2, 5, max, fill = NA), 
         test = as.integer(value1 > last4max))

#                  time value1       value2 test    last4max
#1  2021-02-14 19:30:00   5.68 1.951940e-02   NA          NA
#2                 <NA>     NA 3.872453e-02   NA          NA
#3                 <NA>     NA 1.620312e-03   NA          NA
#4                 <NA>     NA 8.665379e-03   NA          NA
#5                 <NA>     NA 2.440452e-02   NA 0.038724526
#6  2021-02-14 19:35:00   3.57 5.014200e+00    0 5.014200264
#7                 <NA>     NA 3.893854e-03   NA 5.014200264
#8                 <NA>     NA 4.714246e-03   NA 5.014200264
#9                 <NA>     NA 2.390938e-03   NA 5.014200264
#10                <NA>     NA 1.875171e-03   NA 5.014200264
#11 2021-02-14 19:40:00   0.75 6.304860e-04    1 0.004714246
#12                <NA>     NA 1.442379e-03   NA 0.004714246
#13                <NA>     NA 1.261411e-03   NA 0.002390938
#14                <NA>     NA 1.777357e-05   NA 0.001875171
#15                <NA>     NA 3.356436e-04   NA 0.001442379
#16 2021-02-14 19:45:00   0.00 1.277141e-02    0 0.012771405
```

Comment: Ronak, the results do not save into the dataframe df1, just output to Console. How would I correct that?

Comment: @DenisK Assign the result back to dataframe. `df1 <- df1 %>%mutate(last4max ......)`

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using `slider` to pull together the trailing max from four rows before to current:

```
library(slider)
df1$prior_4_max = slide(df1$value2, max, .before = 4)
df1$test = ifelse(df1$prior_4_max < df1$value1, 1, 0)
```

Result

```
> df1
                  time value1       value2 test prior_4_max
1  2021-02-14 19:30:00   5.68 1.951940e-02    1   0.0195194
2                 <NA>     NA 3.872453e-02   NA  0.03872453
3                 <NA>     NA 1.620312e-03   NA  0.03872453
4                 <NA>     NA 8.665379e-03   NA  0.03872453
5                 <NA>     NA 2.440452e-02   NA  0.03872453
6  2021-02-14 19:35:00   3.57 5.014200e+00    0      5.0142
7                 <NA>     NA 3.893854e-03   NA      5.0142
8                 <NA>     NA 4.714246e-03   NA      5.0142
9                 <NA>     NA 2.390938e-03   NA      5.0142
10                <NA>     NA 1.875171e-03   NA      5.0142
11 2021-02-14 19:40:00   0.75 6.304860e-04    1 0.004714246
12                <NA>     NA 1.442379e-03   NA 0.004714246
13                <NA>     NA 1.261411e-03   NA 0.002390938
14                <NA>     NA 1.777357e-05   NA 0.001875171
15                <NA>     NA 3.356436e-04   NA 0.001442379
16 2021-02-14 19:45:00   0.00 1.277141e-02    0  0.01277141
```

Comment: I'm on R version 3.6.0 and will not be able to update. The library Slider is unavailable. Is there a similar function I can possibly use?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a hard-coded version.

```
add_prior_max=function(df) {
  prior_max=numeric(0)
  for (i in 1:nrow(df1)) {
    if (is.na((df1$time)[i])) {
      prior_max[i]=NA
      next
    }
    if (i==1) {
      prior_max[i]=df1$value2[1]
    } else if (i==2) {
      prior_max[i]=max(df1$value2[1], df1$value2[2])
    } else if (i==3) {
      prior_max[i]=max(df1$value2[1], df1$value2[2], df1$value2[3])
    } else if (i==4) {
      prior_max[i]=max(df1$value2[i], df1$value2[i-1], df1$value2[i-2], df1$value2[i-3])
    } else {
      prior_max[i]=max(df1$value2[i], df1$value2[i-1], df1$value2[i-2], df1$value2[i-3], df1$value2[i-4])
    }
  }
  return(mutate(df, prior_max))
}
```

Output

```
> df3=add_prior_max(df1)
> df3
                  time value1       value2 test   prior_max
1  2021-02-14 19:30:00   5.68 1.951940e-02   NA 0.019519404
2                 <NA>     NA 3.872453e-02    1          NA
3                 <NA>     NA 1.620312e-03    1          NA
4                 <NA>     NA 8.665379e-03    1          NA
5                 <NA>     NA 2.440452e-02    1          NA
6  2021-02-14 19:35:00   3.57 5.014200e+00    0 5.014200264
7                 <NA>     NA 3.893854e-03    0          NA
8                 <NA>     NA 4.714246e-03    1          NA
9                 <NA>     NA 2.390938e-03    1          NA
10                <NA>     NA 1.875171e-03    1          NA
11 2021-02-14 19:40:00   0.75 6.304860e-04    0 0.004714246
12                <NA>     NA 1.442379e-03    1          NA
13                <NA>     NA 1.261411e-03    1          NA
14                <NA>     NA 1.777357e-05    1          NA
15                <NA>     NA 3.356436e-04    1          NA
16 2021-02-14 19:45:00   0.00 1.277141e-02    0 0.012771405
```

To calculate the sum:

```
> df3=mutate(df3, test=ifelse(value1>prior_max, 1, 0))
> sum(df3$test, na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 2
```

Comment: I would like to add up the instances of 1's for my result. Is it possible to leave NA on rows that do not have a time?